# How To Call The RenderAction in my Html Helper?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

im extending the htmlhelper. but it i cannot call the renderaction of it.

```
 using System.Text;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
 public static class ViewHelpers
    {
        public static string Text(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, bool isEditMode)
        {
           htmlHelper.RenderAction(...) //cannot be called
        }
    }
```

how can i call the RenderAction???

Comment: @CoffeeCode, further to your comment against my post, can't you pass the domain model to your helper and then work with it?  I'm a little hazy as to what you want to do and whether you have access to the list of elements or whether you want to manipulate the list.

Comment: i just need access to list of elements

Comment: see my edit on my answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the solution was realy easy.
add `using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;`
and when calling the `RenderAction` it will write the html string directly to the view

Comment: RenderAction does not return a string, instead it writes direct to Response.  So while what you're doing in this case may work, it's only by fluke.

Answer (score 3):

CoffeeCode was on the right track, but the namespace to include should be **System.Web**, **System.Web.Mvc** and **System.Web.Mvc.Html**.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Resources;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace xxx.yyy.Helpers {
    public static class HelperView {
        public static void RenderHeader(this HtmlHelper helper) {
            helper.RenderAction("Header", "Default", new { pageAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703490(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 2):

@CoffeeCode, could you explain why you'd like to do this?

Generally speaking you would call a helper to return html as a string which is then rendered in the page.

It seems a little weird to want to render it within the helper.  At least to me anyway.

**edit**

i think a helper here might be the wrong thing for you.  if you want access to the list, but you don't want to pass it to the view then a helper is the wrong place.  You may want to create a class that takes the list, does stuff with it and then return html.

Comment: its just that i have an action that return a view result, which is a dropdown list. i dont whant to pass the list of elements to the view, because i want it simple as possible. and i dont have access to the domain model in my htmlhelper. so im trying to call the RenderAction.